# Apply changes to mainforms Form.Icon at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a System.Windows.Forms.Form and want to change the Form.Icon at runtime to display a status. I've managed to load the icon from the projects ressources:

```
Type type = this.GetType();
System.Resources.ResourceManager resources =
    new System.Resources.ResourceManager(type.Namespace + ".Properties.Resources", this.GetType().Assembly);
this.Icon = (System.Drawing.Icon)resources.GetObject(
    type.Namespace + ".Icons." + statusText + ".ico");
```

But the displayed icon stays the same (design time icon) all the time. Do I have to call a method to tell the Form to apply changes? Something wrong about my usage of Form.Icon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, Siva and Hans where right: GetObject returned null, because the name of the ressource wasn't right. With the following change it works:

```
Type type = this.GetType(); 
System.Resources.ResourceManager resources = 
new System.Resources.ResourceManager(type.Namespace + ".Properties.Resources", this.GetType().Assembly);

// here it comes, call GetObject just with the resource name, no namespace and no extension
this.Icon = (System.Drawing.Icon)resources.GetObject(statusText);
```

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Actually, you are using the Namespace, but it is the Class name you need before ".Properties.Resources".

Answer (score 15):

It is unclear to me why you are doing this the hard way.  Just add the icon to your resources.  Project + Properties, Resource tab, arrow on Add Resource button, Add Existing File.  Then you'd use it like this at runtime:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.Icon = Properties.Resources.Mumble;
    }
```

Where *Mumble* is the name of the icon.

If you are 100% sure that GetObject() doesn't return null then try setting the Icon property in the designer.  If it still doesn't show up then there's something wrong with the icon format.  Make sure that it doesn't have too many colors, 256 works on XP.

Comment: Hi Hans, there is a type casting problem in the code above (bitmap can not be converted to Icon type, i guess). Sorry for that.

Comment: @Siva, Hans sample works without a cast for me. Maybe you haven't added your ressource as an icon?

Comment: thanks, I get a statusText (string) and put the icons in my resources. I want to load them via the statusText (to be flexible to add another status and icon). Your approach works, but isn't flexible ... so I have to check, what I'm doing wrong, when loading the ressource ...

Comment: @Hans There are at least two reasons why do this the "hard way": (1) switching between multiple icons and (2) because of antipathy against designers (my favorite).

Answer (score 3):

I Guess, first of all, your GetObject(...) is returning null. Thats the reason the type casting is ending up silently neither throwing error nor change the icon.

Instead,if possible, use

```
this.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(...)
```

overloads and then give a try.

Comment: ok, never mind, now I got it: I copied the whole namespace crap in the name of the ressource from another sample, that got me null for the GetObject() ... it works this way: this.Icon = (System.Drawing.Icon)resources.GetObject(statusText);

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to change the icon whenever the status of your application changes.

I tested this out with a simple WinForm application:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Icon = Properties.Resources.Gear;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Icon = Properties.Resources.UAC_shield;
}
```

When the program is running, clicking on each button will change the form icon (and, of course, the icon in the taskbar) to the specified icon. I just picked some icons from the set that ships with Visual Studio and added them to the project's Resource file.

You should be able to add a simple method that you can call anywhere in your code which sets the icon (and you can call it from Form_Load as well):

```
private void ChangeIconStatus(string statusText)
{
    Type type = this.GetType();
    System.Resources.ResourceManager resources =
    new System.Resources.ResourceManager(type.Namespace + ".Properties.Resources", this.GetType().Assembly);
    this.Icon = (System.Drawing.Icon)resources.GetObject(type.Namespace + ".Icons." + statusText + ".ico");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"this.Icon" resolves general icon...

But if you want to change the minimized icon of your desktop application, do as follows. This could also work if you want to cover every possibility.

Drag a control "NotifyIcon" (TOOLBOX->COMMON CONTROLS) in your WinForm application. It is transparent, so put it in some corner  ... it doesn't matter.

Click the Form and override RESIZE event.

Copy the following code:

```
/// <summary>
/// GET - if the form is minimized, hide it from the task bar and show the system tray icon 
/// (represented by the NotifyIcon control)   
/// </summary>
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        // CTRL - 
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            // RESET - hide this from taskbar
            Hide();
            // SET - show system tray icon
            notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
                
            // INIT - tray icon
            // change this as you wish - from the Exe PATH, you have to have a
            // "Resources" directory with inside your icon. Just to not put 
            // every icon inside the exe directory...
            Icon tempIcon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon("Resources/myIcon.ico");  
            
            notifyIcon1.Icon = tempIcon;
        }
        // RET
        return;
}
```

The result is that if your program starts MINIMIZED or will be MINIMIZED, the icon will be set by the code.

This solution is in ADDITION to this code that must be put in the "main"

```
        /// <summary>
        /// MAIN - with optional arguments
        /// </summary>
        public Form1(string[] arguments)
        {
            // INIT
            InitializeComponent();
            // INIT - icon of the desktop application
            Icon tempIcon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon("Resources/myIcon.ico");
            this.Icon = tempIcon;
            // RET
            return;
        }
```

bye