# Setting project/application icon programmatically

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I would like to be able to set the icon of a project/application in VS programmatically. NOTE: I know how to do this for individual forms, but I would like to do it for the actual application itself, i.e. the icon that the .exe has (and the one that will show in Uninstall Programs and Files..etc).

You can do this in My Project, but I can't seem to find any way to do this via code?

I know how to use Build Configurations and Custom constants etc and I assume the answer would use something like that?

Thanks for any and all assistance with this!

Comment: That icon in bundled in the .exe itself, as a normal Windows resource, thus it's not changeable once the project has been compiled.

Comment: Does the following do to you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899364/apply-changes-to-mainforms-form-icon-at-runtime

Comment: why would you want to change the icon for the whole executable? Surely it's confusing to the user if the icon changes during execution? What are you trying to gain by doing that?

Comment: I have split the program into two channels. I use a program called squirrel.windows and an app I wrote to basically do all the grunt work of creating two channels and installers/updaters. I want to be able to stick into the project some code that depending on which build config, the app icon should be set. I want to change it AS it is compiled, which can be done via code

Comment: surely better to do that via the build configuration with msbuild, rather than within the application code itself. As you said yourself, it's a compile-time job, not a runtime job.

Comment: Yes that would be fine but the question is how?

Comment: FYI I've achieved this by basically just rewriting the .ico file itself. Not ideal so would still be happy to hear if anyone has a way to do this? It's controlled in the .vbproj file, which can't be edited before build...